# JavaScript - Modifying var declared before, in a function returned by another?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm facing a variable reference issue with JavaScript.. The best way to make it understandable is to show my code :

```
var compiledCode = '';
var lastOutput;

/* ... */

callingFunc(
       function (lastOutput, compiledCode) {
         return function() {
           /* This trims back the lastOutput from compiledCode */
           var trimBackLength = lastOutput.split('\n').length;

           var tmpVar = compiledCode.split('\n');
           tmpVar.splice(0, -trimBackLength);
           compiledCode = tmpVar.join('\n');

           /* And then returns the lastOutput */
           return lastOutput;
         };
       }(lastOutput, compiledCode)
    );
```

And I want my function to be used like this:

```
function callingFunc(newFunc) {
  var v = newFunc();
}
```

So my problem is when I call the "newFunc()", aka. the anonymous function, it returns me what I want but it doesn't trim back in the global variable...
Can you tell me where I made a misatke please ?
Thanks by advance !

Comment: You're returning `lastOutput` without modifying it. maybe You want to `return compiledCode` ?

Comment: No, I wan't to return `lastOutput` but I wan't to modify the global `compiledCode`...

Comment: what about: `var v = newFunc.bind(this)();`

Comment: Thanks num8er, I used a workaround by changing `compiledCode` to `this.compiledCode` and passing a pointer to this in my function, it worked as it should :D

Comment: what You're doing is accessing scopes. that's why there are: `bind`, `apply`, `call` methods to access scope )  so Your `callingFunc` is not good idea :D

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't trim back in the global variable

Of course not, because it doesn't use any global variables. The `compiledCode` variable is the one locally declared as the parameter of your IIFE.

There appears to be no reason to have that in your code, just drop the entire IIFE.

```
var compiledCode = '';
var lastOutput; // you forgot to initialise this

/* ... */

callingFunc(function() {
    /* This trims back the lastOutput from compiledCode */
    var trimBackLength = lastOutput.split('\n').length;
    var tmpVar = compiledCode.split('\n');
    tmpVar.splice(0, -trimBackLength);
    compiledCode = tmpVar.join('\n');

    /* And then returns the lastOutput */
    return lastOutput;
});
```